# different width spacing in horizontal menu tabs

Tags: css, width, spacing

Is it possible to have more space between the list items "exhibition" and "current" and less space between the list items "current" and "previous"? changing the padding-right in #mainmenu2 li changes the space of each one equally.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zuVu7/9/

css

```
  @charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

.bg {
    background-attachment:fixed; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

    }


#mainmenu2
{ 
 position:relative;
  left: 72px;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

#mainmenu2 li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 32px;


}
```

and the html is:

```
    <body class="bg">


<div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="mainmenu2">
<li><span class="secondarytextcolour">EXHIBITION</span></li>
<li><a href="#" class="secondarysubtextcolour">CURRENT</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="secondarysubtextcolour">PREVIOUS</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<img src="line.jpg" align="top" width="100%" height="1" />
</div>

<br />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
#mainmenu2 li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding-right: 15px;


}
#mainmenu2 li span
{
    margin-right:15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the bottom of your CSS, and adjust padding-right as needed:

```
#mainmenu2 li:first-child {
   padding-right: 50px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, give the li a class or ID and reference it. Fiddle with the margin or padding as per your requirements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zuVu7/11/      I think I'm still doing something wrong, added a class in the li called current and added padding to it but no change?